# Access a file from an opening function without calling it

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter

I want to access a file for later use in Tkinter. The file is selected by the user and opened by a function. The function is called by a button. How do I access this file without calling the function again hence triggering the file selector again.

```
def select_file():
filetypes = (
    ('Excel files', '*.xlsx'),
)

filename = fd.askopenfilename(
    title='Open file',
    initialdir='/',
    filetypes=filetypes)

showinfo(
    title='Selected File',
    message=filename
)
df = pd.read_excel(filename, engine='openpyxl')

return df


open_button = tk.Button(
    root,
    text='Select File',
    command=select_file
)
open_button.pack()

df = select_file()
print(df.head())
```

I guess I could maybe make it a global variable within the function? Does not seem very elegant though. I must be missing something obvious. This is, as you might guess my first Tkinter project. Any and all help is appreciated

Comment: If you don't want to use global variable, put related stuff in a class and use instance variable.

Comment: That could really be something. Thanks!

Comment: `select_file` does too much. It should provide the file name for someone *else* to use.

Answer (score 1):

Tkinter callbacks' return values are not reachable so some options are:

- global variable
- a mutable variable, e.g., list and then appending to it
- binding an attribute to the callback function
- forming a class on its own
- ...

Third option:

```
def select_file():
   # ask for it
   file_name = ...

   # bind to function
   select_file.file_name = file_name

# start with None
select_file.file_name = None

# other things...
# e.g., button placement

# somewhere in the program (possibly in a callback), checking the file name
...f_name = select_file.file_name
...if f_name is not None:
      ...
```

Another thing to note is that file name is available only after the user is asked, i.e., after the button is pressed. By that time, whole program is traversed and tkinter mainloop is started, so only tkinter events are being listened to. So, you can use the above `if` in one of those callbacks.

Comment: Won't it just cause the same problem? When the read_excel tries to access the f_name the select_file function will be called? It seems so at least. When I run the program the file selector window is already open, before I press the button "open_button"

Comment: @G_olof You're absolutely right, this is a useless answer sorry about that... Return values of the callbacks cannot be reached directly; so either a global variable `filename` or a persistent structure such as a `list` defined outside the function and then appended inside, or making the file name an attribute of the function, or a class on its own might help.

Comment: @G_olof However, I'm now a bit confused about how you want to use that file name in the program, because it can only be available *once* the user is asked, i.e., only after the button is pressed. By that time, whole program is traversed and tkinter main loop is started, so only tkinter events are being listened to. So you want to use the file name in another tkinter callback functons or something?

Comment: Yeah indeed, thanks a lot for your help. It helped me structure my code better. I realized I could use a callback function instead of making the variable global and achieve the same thing.

Comment: @G_olof I see; that's good to hear. FWIW, to make this answer at least not wrong, I included a way that *might* be useful for some use cases.